# Visual Studio For Mac, при открытии всегда требует скачать mono framework

Tags: visual-studio

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
каждый раз когда запускаю visual studio for mac, он требует скачать mono framework. После установки нормально открывается, но стоит завершить студию и заново открыть, требование повторяется. Проблема именно в том что после успешной установки его хватает на один запуск, и стоит завершить studio как он опять просит установить туже самую версию которую до этого устанавливал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том что во время обновления был запушен Xamarin Studio. Видимо происходит что-то вроде конфликта и нормально не устанавливается. Проблема решилась, просто, завершил все программы, Visual Studio и Xamarin Studio, и запустить установку пакета вручную.